# How to concatenate list in map function - Haskell?

Tags: function, haskell

I have two functions:

```
fun1 :: Int -> [Int]
fun2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

`fun2` accept `Int list` and apply `fun1` to each element of this list with help `map`. But `fun1` return `[Int]`. So, I have type conflict. How to solve my problem?

Comment: Should fun2 be as follows `fun2 :: [Int] -> [[Int]]`

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do? Is it just to fix the type conflict?

Comment: An example could clarify the enquiry...

Comment: most likely you are looking for [`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:concatMap) instead of `map` (as in `fun2 = concatMap fun1`) - `concatMap fun1` will apply `fun1` to each element in the input list but will flatten all the resulting lists into one by concatenating them

Comment: Sorry guys for my silence. I was out of the computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely want a combination of `map` and `concat` to achieve it. Assuming `fun1` and `fun2` are something like this:

```
fun1 :: Int -> [Int]
fun1 x = [x,x]

fun2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
fun2 = map (+ 1)

solution :: [Int] -> [Int]
solution xs = concat $ map fun1 (fun2 xs)
```

Or as suggested by @CarstenKonig, you can use `concatMap`

```
solution2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
solution2 xs = concatMap fun1 $ fun2 xs
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
solution2 :: [Int] -> [Int]
solution2 = concatMap fun1 . fun2
```

Comment: based on "fun2 accept Int list and apply fun1 to each element of this" I would think that the OP really just wants `fun2 = concatMap fun1` though -  but yeah that's another one that *type-checks* ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig I felt this was the natural answer to OP :) But yes, I may be wrong.

Comment: that's the problem (not with your answer) - the question is not really good but the OP don't seem to be able to clarify right now

Answer (score 4):

The ability to transform `[[a]]` to `[a]` is what make `List` (among other thing) a Monad.
Therefore you can use the do notation :

```
fun2 xs = do 
     x <- xs
     fun1 x
```

which can the be rewritten `fun2 xs = xs >>= fun1` or even better

```
fun2 = (>>= fun1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is with list comprehension. Mapping `fun1` over the list `xs` is

```
fun2' xs = [ fun1 x | x <- xs ]
     --  =  map fun1 xs
     --  =  do x <- xs                -- for each x in xs:
     --        return (fun1 x)        --    yield (fun1 x)
```

which indeed would have a different type than what you wanted.

To flatten it one step further we do

```
fun2  xs = [ y | x <- xs, y <- fun1 x ]
     --  = concatMap fun1 xs
     --  =  do x <- xs                -- for each x in xs:
     --        y <- fun1 x            --    for each y in (fun1 x):
     --        return y               --       yield y
```